# Changing the font size of field Label entry text in Cognito Forms

Tags: cognito-forms, customization

Is it possible to change the size of the Label font for the Rating Scale and Repeating Section fields?

Answer (score 1):

If you are embedding your [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com), you can use CSS to fully customize the appearance of any element.  Here is an article that provides a basic overview of using CSS with Cognito Forms:

http://blog.cognitoforms.com/styling-cognito-forms-with-css

We try to use appropriate HTML5 semantic markup as much as possible, so in the case of Rating Scale and Repeating Sections, these headers are actually `<h3>` tags, and our forms are always included in a `<div>` that has the class `cognito` applied to it, so you could use the following to adjust the font size for both:

```
.cognito h3 { font-size: 110%; }
```